# Bitrix не создан временный каталог для загрузки

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Пытаюсь загрузить на сайт изображение, но `bitrix` пишет что не создан временный каталог для загрузки.

в phpinfo показывает что временный каталог `/tmp/php_upload/www`
проверяю на хостинге, папка существует.

В чем может быть проблема ? Пароль от админки забыли, я обнулил его через запуск скрипта на сервере, могли он сбросить какие либо настройки ?

Погугли пока ничего не помогает, дал права на папки, каталог вроде есть, как быть ?

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/forum6/topic84365/

Comment: я гуглик и 100 раз просматривал это, не помогает

Comment: А случайно не drag&drop испольщзуете?

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте права на папку

```
/tmp/php_upload/www
```

Настройки / Инструменты / Проверка системы / Проверка доступа